# How to find all php-pear usages in a PHP project?

Tags: php, phpstorm, pear

We are having this large PHP Project. There is `php-pear` installed, via

`apt-get install`

We got no clue for what we needed that for.

Now we need to find out if any PEAR-related class/method/function is in use in the PHP project.

Thing is, as I mentioned, it's a huge project and I joined the project a year ago, that's why I got no clue how many of the features that come with the apt-get packages are in use.

Used IDE is PhpStorm, just in case, there is a feature to accomplish this.

So if there's any command we could use on the Linux shell or anything we could do on PhpStorm, I'd be grateful for any hint.

Comment: You could try [analyzing backward dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyzing-backward-dependencies.html) on the pear packages. Though I can't tell how well that works for pear installs!?

Comment: Why don't you just list all PEAR installs? `pear list-files`. This gives you a list what is installed. When moving to a new server for instance you know what is needed.

Comment: Or uninstall all the PEAR modules, run the code, look at the errors. Add the required modules back one at a time, then you get all you need and none of the ones that got installed and never used

Comment: As I can see PEAR provides only functions available in PECL extension: https://pear.php.net/manual/en/about.pear.php. So it looks like as long as you have PECL enabled - you're good to get rid of pear. In PhpStorm you can also invoke Ctrl(cmd)+Shift+F and search for "pear" to see if there are any mentions of it in a code.

Comment: If you have tests in place, you can remove `php-pear`, run your tests and find out what crashes...

Answer (score 1):

1. Find out which pear packages have been installed with `pear list`
2. Search for classes beginning with the package name, e.g. `XML_Util` (In PEAR, all classes must be prefixed with the package name).